# Exclude IP adress from spring security cas filter

Tags: spring-security, web-crawler

I have a site that uses CAS as a SSO solution and require all that access the site to be authenticated. To fulfill the regulations that our company has we need to create fully rendered snapshot copies of the site. I was thinking of using something like Httrack to accomplish this, but I need to get around the login. My plan was to exclude the IP address of the server running httrack, but I cannot seem to figure out how to configure this.

```
    <sec:http name="contentSecurityFilterChain" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="contentAccessDecisionManager" entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <sec:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter" />
      <sec:logout logout-success-url="/logout.jsp" logout-url="/j_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="sessionKey,userId,lastClient" />
      <sec:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
      <sec:custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
      <sec:custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />

      <sec:csrf disabled="true" />

      <sec:headers>
        <!-- Enable hsts if possible. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797 -->
        <sec:hsts disabled="true" />
        <sec:cache-control disabled="true" />
        <sec:frame-options disabled="true" />
      </sec:headers>

      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitoring/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MONITORING')" requires-channel="${security.channel.dispatcher}" />
channel="${security.channel.dispatcher}" />
      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/login" access="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED')" />
      <sec:intercept-url  pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED') or hasIpAddress('192.168.123.123')" requires-channel="${security.channel.dispatcher}" />
    </sec:http>
```

I tried the above as a first attempt (where 192.168.123.123 represents my excluded server), but the request still gets redirected to the SSO site before returning to the filter chain.

The closest I got in my various naive fiddlings was by adding a filter to the entry point that did not trigger the commence method; While it did not redirect the request, it only returned an empty page. I assume that is because by not calling the commence method the request was seen as not matching the filter group.

Is there a way to exclude an IP address from the security filters OR is there a better way of doing this?

Suggestions most welcomed!